# Android Stuio: Complete project structure lost after importing/reopening project from a backup

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So I was forced to delete my Android Studio project and restore it from a backup (a complete copy of the previously working project folder). Now, when I open Android Studio, all files and the complete project structure - everything is gone and Android Studio just displays an empty project pane.

Closing the project and reopening it, or even importing it again does not change anything. No files are displayed at the Project Pane anymore. Although they are located in the projects directory. 
Also the run configurations are gone as well as all configurations made at `File -> Project Structure`. In other words, the whole project is gone - except the files, they are still here, but Android Studio has all of a sudden no clue what to do with them anymore.
How can this be repaired?

Any advice is welcome, thank you!

Comment: pls share a screenshot of your workspace. it may help us to find the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its a gradle project, press the Gradle Sync button and it will restore the project structure.

Comment: It turned out, that it was caused by a broken (beta) plugin. The Gradle Sync button was disabled (grayed out), and the workspace was completely empty (not even the files of an empty/new project where showing) after the project has been imported/opened. Disabling the plugin, importing the project again and hitting the Gradle Sync button fixed it. Thank you for pointing in the right direction.